# Java/Android rounded drawable/bitmap - 4 diffrent radiuses and size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, drawable

I searched but not found any clue to help my problem:

I have an ImageView with some layer drawable that presents border radiuses to that view. Also I set jpg/png file that should present its background(and should be more like css equivalent to code shortly like `'background-image:url(....)'`),

My main issue is that when jpg/png file is small theres a problem that it is first cornered, and then stretched, and cause of result image looks more like circle, not like stretched rectangle with rounded corners.

Important note:I have 4 different corner-radiuses(any number from 0 to 1000), like in web radius-top-left,radius-top-right, etc.

Anyone had problem like that or know better way of implementing this?

I tried to add use custom drawable:

```
public class RoundCornersBitmap extends PaintDrawable {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final BitmapShader mShader;
    private final ImageView mView;

    public RoundCornersBitmap(Bitmap bmp, ImageView view) {
        mBitmap = bmp;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setShader(mShader);
        mPaint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        mView = view;
        //example corners
        this.setCornerRadii(new float[]{50, 50, 120, 120, 90, 90, 40, 40});
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmap.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return mPaint;
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        getShape().draw(canvas, mPaint);
    }

}
```

and my with layer list presents as folowing:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item>
               <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#ff00ff"></solid>
                   <corners android:topLeftRadius="50px" android:topRightRadius="120px"
                           android:bottomLeftRadius="90px"
                           android:bottomRightRadius="40px"></corners>
                <padding android:top="20px" android:left="20px" android:right="20px" android:bottom="20px"></padding>
               </shape>
           </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f0000f"></solid>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="50px" android:topRightRadius="120px"
                     android:bottomLeftRadius="90px"
                     android:bottomRightRadius="40px"></corners>
            <padding android:top="1px" android:bottom="1px" android:left="1px" android:right="1px"></padding>
            </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

addinationaly my layout.xml presents like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sk"
            android:layout_width="320px"
            android:layout_height="380px"
            android:background="@drawable/skdrawable"
            android:src="@drawable/ski2"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

also code in my activity that should do the task:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sk);
        BitmapDrawable d = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ski2);

         view.setImageDrawable(new RoundCornersBitmap(d.getBitmap(),view));
```

I'd appreciate any help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround with using extra path in my imageview:

```
Rect outRect = new Rect();
        getDrawingRect(outRect);
        mPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(outRect.left,outRect.top, width,height), floats_array, Path.Direction.CW);
```

and clipping it in onDraw:

```
canvas.clipPath(mPath);
```